# SIP vs direct TCP sockets

Tags: android, tcp, sip, rtp

I am implementing a real time - multi user voice transfer application for Android.
I have read that, as a standard -  RTP packets are encapsulated into SIP and then sent to destination(s). What is the advantage of doing so?

my idea was to use a server, just to receive control messages from nodes and open sockets. All these nodes would be in 1 group. THen, I send out the IP addresses of each of these nodes, so that a single sender can multicast its packets directly to the destination.

is there a fatal flaw here? ( iam not concerned about the power consumption)
How does SIP do better? or does it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIP or Session Initiation Protocol is a protocol that was designed specifically to address the problem you're trying to solve. Generally, the reason you should reuse (rather than reinvent the wheel) is because other people have studied the same problem and presumably have come up with a better solution as a collective group than you could as an individual. Of course that's not always true, but generally speaking it holds!

If you want to learn about SIP you could study the [RFC 3261 specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt), or start with the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) if you want a quick overview.

That being said, if you *don't need* the overhead of a complete and carefully tested protocol you could roll your own but make sure that when you're making that decision you know what you're foregoing and have a good reason to do so.

SIP is a signaling protocol that usually runs over TCP (although not required) and if you look at it closely you will see it is very similar to HTTP in many respects. Just like HTTP it can transport a great deal of payloads and it does so with text headers, much like HTTP can be used to transport HTML, XML, plain text or any arbitrary binary payload.

Comment: so what's the point of sip ? I just want a socket connection, to the server from my node. Once I receive the addresses, I may start my direct rtp packet transmission. Even if one node breaks, I don't care... am just going to test with a few nodes insode 1 access point.. so, don't think the performance would vary much... would it ?

Comment: The socket is nice, but you need to think about NAT traversal issues - especially for the RTP stuff. For that, using something like SIP means it will be easier to manage as solutions already exist there (STUN, TURN, ICE) and you can get these from third parties readily available. Same logic applies for other features such as multipoint support, security, etc.

Comment: The point of SIP is that it is an already established protocol for doing what you're trying to do. Even if you're only going to need a small subset of SIP features initially you might still benefit from implementing partial SIP support as your signaling protocol.

Comment: SIP most commonly runs over UDP (check voip services and ATAs...); Microsoft requires SIP-over-TCP (actually I think over TLS).

Answer (score 3):

- RTP isn't "encapsulated into SIP packets".  SIP is a signalling protocol.  RTP is a media stream protocol.  SIP is used to negotiate and set up (and tear down) media streams.
- TCP is a horrible choice for media (RTP) packets; it's not clear from your writing if you're suggesting that.
- Multicast is unlikely to work for many network paths/recipients.
- routers play merry hell with incoming data; you'll need more than just SIP to deal with users on the open net.  See STUN, TURN, ICE, UPnP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the most simple system, you could just use Voice packets over RTP over UDP.

But you'd have no way to turn audio off, and would have to know IP addresses, port numbers, they type of codec and its characteristics beforehand.

In an overly simple view, SIP is a way to:
1. find the ip address of another endpoint from a URL. (May need STUN, TURN, ICE, etc)
2. agree on which codec to use and its options

There's a lot more to SIP than that, you may want to investigate SIP's conferencing features based on what you wrote.

You may write your own signaling protocol, and if this is for a school project, that will work just fine.

But if you are doing a commercial project, bear in mind that there is a lot more to telephony than meets the eye.  The original SIP spec was greatly revised and is now a cluster of RFCs which are still being modified and added to.  I recommend that you take advantage of this work rather than possibly reinventing the mistakes others have made.